# Self-mined Badge Progress via 2.0+ API

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges

Badge Progress as a topic has had many questions, and some closed. Before downvoting or closing, please consider how this question might be different.

First, what's the the latest official answer of Badge Progress for long-commitment badges - for example:  `Archaeologist: Edited 100 posts that were inactive for 6 months`?

Assuming it is not going to be made visible from the user profile or Badges page, could such data be exposed through the 2.0+ API so as to allow users to mine the data on their own time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm declining this, not because I don't see the merit in it, but because we don't have the data to return in anything approaching a reasonable time.

Our badge awarding code is very complex, and intentionally run in staggered (and even, in some cases, random) schedule to prevent DOS-ing our own databases.  Opening those queries up via an API would be unacceptably dangerous.

Naturally, since I do see the merit, if this state of affairs changes I'll revisit this request.

Comment: Thank you, Kevin. Especially for the explanation as it makes a lot of sense. I also see Jeff's thoughts in that, the badges should not become a game or the central motivation anyway.